# pdo insert statement using datetime errors

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, timestamp

I have a table with a field with type as TIMESTAMP

On my webpage i have two fields and the values being sent out are as follow.

```
$eDate = "Wed, 01 Apr 2015";
$eTime = "11:35 pm";
```

Using the following code i am trying to insert the values in the table

```
$str = trim($eDate) . " " . trim($eTime);
$eventDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("D\, d M Y g:i a", $str);

$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server_name;dbname=$db_name", $username, $password);
$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$dateCreated = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

//insert record
$statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO events VALUES(DEFAULT, AES_ENCRYPT(:newEntryTitle,'$secretKey'), AES_ENCRYPT(:newEntry,'$secretKey'), :eventDate, :uid, :submission_date)");
$statement->bindParam(':newEntryTitle', $entity_elm2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':newEntry', $entity_elm1, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':eventDate', $eventDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'), PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->bindParam(':uid', $_SESSION["UserID"]);
$statement->bindParam(':submission_date', $dateCreated);
$statement->execute();
$last_id = $conn->lastInsertId();
```

I am getting an error

> Call to a member function format() on a non-object

I have struggled with this for hours without any resolutions.
Can someone help. Please

Comment: and if you `var_dump($eventDateTime)` before you start your sql stuff, what does it produce?

Comment: @pala_ see the [link](http://ideone.com/e.js/5RNZ6O)

Comment: did you get the same error with `echo($eventDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s')." -------- ");` ?

Comment: @pala_ no. The var_dump produces `object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2015-04-01 23:35:00.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(3)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(3) "UTC"
}`

Comment: Then you are somehow deleting/overwriting `$eventDateTime` before your pdo calls. is that ALL of the code, in sequence? or is it cherrypicked? what if you do `$ts = $eventDateTime->format(....)` after you create `$eventDateTime`, and then try binding `$ts` instead?

Comment: @pala_ It is all the code. The following lines throw the same error `$str = trim($eDate) . " " . trim($eTime);
    $eventDateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("D\, d M Y g:i a", $str);

    echo($eventDateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'));` **Call to a member function format() on a non-object **

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TIMESTAMP data type should accept timestamp. Change the line

```
$statement->bindParam(':eventDate', $eventDateTime->getTimestamp() ...
```

Comment: Same error. **Call to a member function format() on a non-object**

Comment: Your `$eventDateTime` variable content is somehow replaced to something else, null perhaps.

Comment: No. I have checked it several times.

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys. I have it sorted. The issue was not with script. Issue was with the inputs i was receiving. The date part was "2015-5-1" instead of the way i described it. Changed the format and the issue is gone.